# Why does my smooth scroll function jump to the top of the page?

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

Attempting to use jQuery to achieve a smooth scroll when using the nav on a page.  The below code is working, it will take me where I want to go wherever I click, but the scroll effect is only working for the 'else' part

Any advice on what the issue is and how to correct?

```
$('header a').click(function(){
    var thisSection = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(thisSection);

        if (thisSection == '#logo') {

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: top}, 800,
                'easeOutCirc');

            console.log('scenario #1');

        } else {

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(thisSection).offset().top -100}, 800,
                'easeOutCirc');

            console.log('scenario #2');

        }

    return false;
});
```

I've console.logged both the 'if' and 'else' to ensure both are working fully and they are.  I am completely uncertain why the animation isn't queuing when I go to #logo (this is essentially hitting the home button and returning to the top).  Instead, it warps me up there.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question an not just announce that you have one.